# Material Chips: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException when checked any of the chips

Tags: android, kotlin, material-ui, material-design

I have a [chip group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2i1Fw.png) with some chips in my `AddItemFragment`. I am creating these chips programmatically. To be more precise here is my code to create them:

```
     mViewModel.categories.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { resource ->
                handleResource(
                    resource = resource,
                    successFunc = {
                        setCategoryChips(resource.data!!)
                    },
                    errorFunc = {
                        requireView().snack(resource.message!!, R.color.color_danger)
                    }
                )            
        }
    private fun setCategoryChips(categories: List<Kitchen>) {
        for (i in categories.indices) {
            val chip = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_chip, binding.chipGroup, false) as Chip
            if (i == 0) {
                selectedChip = chip.text.toString()
                chip.isChecked = true
            }
            chip.text = categories[i].name
            binding.chipGroup.addView(chip)
        }
        binding.chipGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener { group, checkedId ->
            if (group.childCount > 0) {
                selectedChip = (group.get(checkedId -1) as Chip).text.toString()
                Log.i(TAG, "setCategoryChips: $selectedChip")
            }
        }
    }
```

As you may see I am getting a list from the server then creating chips based on the list. I am getting the text of the checked chip using:

```
binding.chipGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener { group, checkedId ->
            if (group.childCount > 0) {
                selectedChip = (group.get(checkedId -1) as Chip).text.toString()
                Log.i(TAG, "setCategoryChips: $selectedChip")
            }
        }
```

The first time I navigate to my `AddItemFragment` this method works as expected. But when I navigate to another destination then navigating back to `AddItemFragment` again, if I check any of the chips I am getting this error

```
 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 29, Size: 28
        at androidx.core.view.ViewGroupKt.get(ViewGroup.kt:32)
        at com.example.semekyepeti.view.fragments.sellerflow.AddItemFragment$setKitchenChips$1.onCheckedChanged(AddItemFragment.kt:183)
        at com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup.setCheckedId(ChipGroup.java:362)
        at com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup.setCheckedId(ChipGroup.java:355)
        at com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup.access$900(ChipGroup.java:56)
        at com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup$CheckedStateTracker.onCheckedChanged(ChipGroup.java:546)
        at com.google.android.material.chip.Chip.setChecked(Chip.java:714)
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:135)
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:140)
```

I realize that when I navigate to another destination then navigating back to `AddItemFragment` again, the `checkedId` incrementing itself.

```
 I/AddItemFragment: navigate 0 time
 I/AddItemFragment: checkedId: 2
 I/AddItemFragment: item count: 28

 I/AddItemFragment: navigate 1 time
 I/AddItemFragment: checkedId: 30
 I/AddItemFragment: item count: 28
```

So I changed `checkedId -1` with `(checkedId - listCount * navigateCount) -1` to handle this:

```
      binding.chipGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener { group, checkedId ->
            if (group.childCount > 0) {
                selectedChip =
                    (group.get((checkedId - 28 * navigateCount) - 1) as Chip).text.toString() //workaround
            }
        }
```

But I know this is inefficient.I want to get the text of the checked chip. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *checkedId* you're getting is apparently a view ID, and you're meant to grab the actual chip with `findViewById`. You're using it as an index in the viewgroup, which isn't necessarily going to match (but sometimes does!)

And no the documentation doesn't actually explain this

Comment: Okey I have tried `if (group.childCount > 0) { val chip=group.findViewById(checkedId) selectedChip = chip.text.toString()}` as you have said and that's worked.I think that's better than the other way.Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't bother with the count check to be honest, the callback's just saying "here's the ID of the selected chip" (which might be ``NO_ID`` btw, if nothing's selected) and you can just grab it from the view hierarchy. But yeah, that's the way it's supposed to work apparently!